# Singleton OR Static class, which is good for Logging implementation

Tags: c#, oop

I want write my own logger class for logging purpose only and use it in entire application.
***Logger.cs:** Currently I will use it to store logs in physical file, but in future I can extend it to store logs in database also.*

I have read many posts related to difference between static class and singleton and where to use them, but I am still not sure, which I will use for my logger class.

Please help me to know which approach is best fitted for my logger class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To answer you question, I like singletons better because you still get they're easier to test and you still have inheritance.  To answer you problem.  Don't write you're own logger class. Use a nuget package.

Comment: Definitely `Singleton` .

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you think is a singleton class, and what you think is a static class?

Comment: Even I am in favor to use the Singleton, but my co-worker said that in static class we have to write the less line of codes and can achieve the same purpose, as we only need to do logging. Is in future static class can block us anywhere?

Comment: @VaibhavAgrawal It would be awesome if you could ask your co-worker to write the two different versions (even just a cutdown version, with just two or three methods). Then post them here so we can compare the two. Otherwise, I suspect different people are going to interpret the terms you are using differently to others.

Comment: Well it depends. Do you plan on using inheritence down the road, like having `DebugLogger`, `SystemLogger` or something? Even if you aren't planning on doing so, keep in mind that you might change your mind later on, and it could be a real pain to convert from a static class to a singleton. Static classes also can't have virtual members as they all have to be static methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a static class, the number of code lines will be less. But I myself prefer using singleton since creating more than one instance is not possible in singleton it will be more secure.